# Is it OK to update the whole composable or should I optimize?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have built a simple app using Jetpack Compose. This is a simplified game of Wordle (https://www.nytimes.com/games/wordle/index.html)

[image: See the screenshot below]
[image: A guess and the score]

Here is how the game is played

1. There is a 5 letter target word that the app has decided.
2. User types various letters to make a 5 letter word as a guess.
3. After user hits Enter key, the score is given for the guessed word and displayed in a row
4. As user keeps guessing more words, we fill the guessed words in the rows of the grid
5. The guessed letters are colored according to if they are present in the target word and if they are in the correct position.
6. Implementation-wise, there are two columns created. One contains the top grid and the other contains the keyboard buttons. The grid contains rows of grid cells. Gridcell is a composable.
7. The state for the game board is a single object that contains the state of keyboard and the grid cells. Only one single monolith state rather than one for each composable.

My question is that is it OK to recompose the whole UI after every keystroke? One keystroke only affects a single cell of the grid or maybe the whole row of the grid if user hits "Enter".
Is Jetpack Compose renderer intelligent enough to not perform an expensive update if nothing has changed in most of the grids? Or should I be careful and only redraw the portion that has changed?

Comment: It's mostly intelligent enough. Do it the most straightforward way and only optimize if there is a problem. But I'm pretty sure this will be fine.